# Cordova iOS App shows header and footer but blank white content When App put to background and foreground again the Blank white content shows up

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

There is an issue I am facing with building an iOS Cordova app.

Firstly,
Versions

```
cordova: 8.1.2
cordova-ios: 4.5.5(not allowed to upgrade this)
```

The app builds using the cordova terminal commands

when I open the generated Xcode project(in Xcode 12) and run the project from there I get following error:

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='gap://ready'
```

I tried fixing this by doing  in my config.xml
I tried adding meta tags allowing gap://ready in index.html but in both cases,
I got following error:

```
[Process] 0x7ff5e401b820 - [pageProxyID=20, webPageID=21, PID=4458] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID = 15, domain = NSURLErrorDomain, code = -1002
```

basically I got NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL.

So I removed the change  and got back to previous error of gap://ready

I used Safari Web Inspector and added a breakpoint in the cordova.js file where gap://ready was being set as a url to hit in the app.

```
  // Check if they've removed it from the DOM, and put it back if so.
    if (execIframe && execIframe.contentWindow) {
        execIframe.contentWindow.location = 'gap://ready';
    } else {
        execIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        execIframe.style.display = 'none';
        execIframe.src = 'gap://ready';
        document.body.appendChild(execIframe);
    }
```

The above snippet code was running continuously and my app was not accepting gap://ready as url. **Meanwhile I just put the app to background and back to foreground again the blank content issue was fixed. But wait, So It some links and buttons. I tapped on one of those, nothing happened. I put the app again in background and then in foreground a second after that, the pressed button action was called.** Similarly, any action I wanted to perform in the app the same background/foreground switching was working.

Now I have read about WKWebView not supporting iframes(https://cordova.apache.org/news/2018/08/01/future-cordova-ios-webview.html)

Could this be the issue here?

Additionally, I played with cordova.js code as well. Commented it, not let it execute and stuff like that but no luck.

I have been trying to get this working since 2 days now but no luck. Any help is appreciated. Please let me know what your thoughts are.

Thanks in advance.